# Can't get layout info when creating activity

Tags: android

I have this element in my layout XML:

```
<FrameLayout android:id="@+id/FrameLayout01"
 android:layout_width="320sp" android:layout_height="380sp"
 android:layout_gravity="center" android:background="#99CC33">
</FrameLayout>
```

And I want to get its position on the screen with `getTop()`, `getBottom()`,... but I want to do it only once.
I was trying to do it on the onCreate(), but those methods return all 0 as response.

Any tips?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is that the screen isn't created before the onCreate.  For example I used to try and get the screen height and width in the onCreate but it doesn't work because it's not set up yet.  To solve the problem I used a custom View and overrode the function onSizeChanged.

Comment: Well... that's an answer... but i'll need to pass a callback to my other class, and it will be called just one time...

Comment: you can also override onLayout method, once that method is over your size is set... it's not called only once since the screen size can change in an event of orientation or Activity's death.